# Minimum number of columns in grid

Tags: css, css-grid

Keep in mind the value for the number of columns is dynamic, and can be set to any number between 2 and 5 columns.

I have two breakpoints for "tablet" and "desktop" and I want to have the number of columns for tablet be one less than desktop. However, I am trying to find a way to set a minimum number of columns for tablet as I don't want the number of columns to be 1 if "2" was selected.

I have the following (abbreviated) code so far:

```
.some-grid {
  --columns: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
}

@media (min-width: 751px) {
  .some-grid {
    /* This would output 1 column, but would like to set it to 2 minimum */
    --columns: calc(var(--columns-large) - 1);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .some-grid {
    --columns-large: 2;
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: _I don't want the number of columns to be 1 if "2" was selected._ How are the column counts being set? That is important information.

Comment: User can login and customize this setting in the admin (via a select element).

Comment: Is the markup output from the server or is a JS setting when the user views the grid? There might be better ways to approach what you're doing on the server side and use data-attributes to store that information in the markup.

Comment: Markup output from the server. That was the next approach I'd go with, although wanted to see if it was possible in CSS first before doing so :)

Comment: You would still use CSS. You are simply adding attributes so CSS can target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max()`

```css
.some-grid {
  --columns: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
}

@media (min-width: 751px) {
  .some-grid {
    --columns: max(2,var(--columns-large) - 1);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
  .some-grid {
    --columns-large: 2;
  }
}

/**/
.some-grid {
  gap:5px;
}
.some-grid * {
  height:40px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```